# Check if value if exists and return the object in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to check if the value exists in the array and once it exists I need to get the object.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [purok] => test
                    [year] => 2017
                    [options] => below-1
                )

            [data] => Array
                (
                    [58cf4935572d6e32900057ab] => Array
                        (
                            [age-sex-distribution] => Array
                                (
                                    [age-range] => Array
                                        (
                                            [options] => below-1
                                        )

                                    [gender] => Array
                                        (
                                            [male-distribution-count] => 12
                                            [female-distribution-count] => 12
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [date] => 2017-07-08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [purok] => test
                    [year] => 2017
                    [options] => toddlers (1-2)
                )

            [data] => Array
                (
                    [58cf4935572d6e32900057ab12] => Array
                        (
                            [age-sex-distribution] => Array
                                (
                                    [age-range] => Array
                                        (
                                            [options] => toddlers (1-2)
                                        )

                                    [gender] => Array
                                        (
                                            [male-distribution-count] => 12
                                            [female-distribution-count] => 12
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [date] => 2017-07-08
        )

)
```

I need to check this `[options] => below-1` if it exists. One it exist, I need to get the `data` in the array.

So far, I have tried this one.

```
$keySearch = "data.options";
$dataOption = array_search("below-1", array_column($rec, $keySearch));
print_r($dataOption);
```

But got no result.

Thanks for helping me in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$temp = [];

for ($data as $value){
   if($value['_id']['options'] == 'below-1'){
       $temp[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($temp);
```

you can try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
     if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($haystack as $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && search_array($needle, $element))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}

if(!search_array($value, $array)) {
     // do something if the given value does not exist in the array
}else{
     // do something if the given value exists in the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this :

```
for($i=0; $i < count($rec); $i++) {
     if ($rec[$i]['_id']['options'] === "below-1") {
          $dataOption = $rec[$i]['data'];
          break;
     }
}
print_r($dataOption);
```

It should do what you expect ;-)